# increasing the height of a div that is in a row?

Tags: html, css, grid-layout

As you can see from the livelink and code below, I have created a responsive grid layout and its all working wonderfully, however now the last thing I need to do is to make a couple of the squares rectangular.

The ones I need to make rectangular are the top two squares in the second column of my grid and the last two squares in the bottom row of my grid. As you can see I have done the horizontal rectangle, now I need to do the same vertically with the top two squares in the second column. However just increasing the height of the square will distort the whole row.

Can somebody please show me how to do this in a really simple way? As I have tried it and not been able to do it properly.

Thanks

***CSS***

```
.trigger{
    width:200px; 
    height:200px; 
    margin-right:15px;
    margin-bottom:15px; 
}
.hover-img, 
.hover-img.hover_effect  {
    background-color:white;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; 
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #4595ff;
}
.trigger:hover > .hover-img {
     -webkit-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    -ms-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    transform:rotateY(360deg);
    font-size:14px;
    color:white;
}

.img1 {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
.img1:hover{
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.img2 {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.img2:hover{
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.img3 {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
} 
.img3:hover{
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.img4 {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.img4:hover{
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.img5 {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.img5:hover{
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.img6 {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.img6:hover{
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#container{
    width:960px; margin: 0 auto;
}

.row{
    display: flex;
}
```

***HTML***

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="trigger">
            <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img1"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="trigger">
            <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img2"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="trigger">
            <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="trigger">
            <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img4"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div  class="row">
        <div class="trigger">
            <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img5"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="trigger">
            <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img6"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="trigger">
            <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img5"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="trigger">
            <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img6"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div  class="row">
        <div class="trigger">
            <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img5"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="trigger">
            <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img6"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="trigger">
            <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img5"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="trigger">
            <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img6"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you lokking for something like this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b2Lpq9an/)**

CSS:

```
.trigger.vertical {
    height: 415px;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
.trigger.vertical * {
    height: 415px;
}
```